# What does "PowerPoint can't access because the filename is invalid." mean?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I cannot save a file in PowerPoint after I have made recent changes to it. When I click save, there comes a dialog box saying what I have already mentioned in the question. I cannot perform a save as operation also, because the same box pops up. What would be the possible solution? Sorry, if I am being too naive.

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: It is just "DESIGN PROJECT".

Comment: Maybe it's the folder name you want to save your file to that makes PP angry? Or the overall length of the path. "In the Windows API, the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior." Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: The whole morning I was confronted with this dialog box while trying to save and I even tried restarting and changing the file name. But, then when I tried saving after a couple of hours, it saved just fine. I am sure I didn't make any changes in between and it makes me annoyed. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my post but I still would love to find out why it was so.

Comment: The fact that it "self-cured" after a while suggests that some other process was holding the file open (and that PPT responded with a red herring error message; not that unusual of it). Look for automatic backup processes, the file being displayed in the Preview window of Windows Explorer, possibly the file being attached in an email message previously, etc.  The usual workaround is to save to a new name.

Comment: Yes, I remember attaching the file to an email previously, but the email had been delivered successfully and I had closed the mail application. Anyway, probably that is what made the trouble. Thanks for helping to solve the mystery (at least to me, it was that :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means that there is one or more characters that are not allowed in the name of the file. Try saving it without any special characters.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not that. The file name is just 'DESIGN PROJECT'. I tried changing it too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are several factors for the error:

1. When PPT file is active in PowerPoint application, sudden system shutdown or application terminating can sometimes corrupt PPT file that was opened.
2. Adding infected video clippings to PowerPoint file may result in damaging entire PPT file.
3. Malware infection is another prominent factor due to which presentation file can get severely corrupt.
4. Trying to open presentation files on incompatible PowerPoint versions may damage that file.
5. Malfunctioning of PowerPoint application due to incorrect update, wrong installation and other logical errors can sometimes destroy the file.
6. When the filename consists of characters like <, >, /, \, ?, *, :, | or any other characters not supported in PowerPoint filename or extension.

I search a PowerPoint repair tool, we can use it if we need in the future.

[PowerPoint Repair Toolbox](https://www.pptrepairtoolbox.com/)

Comment: But, how can we explain it being automatically resolved after sometime?